# How to stop messaging center to stop subscribe multiple time in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, messagingcenter

I am creating an application and in that it need to send argument to the other page and send argument using the Messagingcenter when I send using MessagingCenter it call more than one time.

If I am using unscribe than in next time it is not receive next time.

```
MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Invoke", "Invokedtrue");

MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage, string>(this, "Invoke", async (sender, arg) =>
{
    await Process(arg);
});
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MyPage>(this,"Invoke");


**ListPage**

    private void ViewCell_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Invoke", "Invokedtrue");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex);
        }
    }

**Detail Page**

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ListPage, string>(this, "Invoke", async (sender, arg) =>
    {
        await Process(arg);
    });

    private async Task Process(string arg)
    {
        //Here is api call to view detail of particular record

        //Here I unsubscribe the MessagingCenter.
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ListPage>(this,"Invoke");
    }
```

I want to send only one time using subscribe and send only one time.

Can anyone look into this and suggest me what should I have to do in that?

Comment: Are you saying the subscribe hits multiple times in the second page?

Comment: are you sure you are not calling send or subscribe multiple times?  Also, the arguments you use in Send<T1,T2> should match those you use when calling Subscribe<T1,T2>

Comment: Hi @Jason Yes I am sure that I only click single time but it subscribe more than one time. So execution process takes too long. Can you please suggest what should we have to do in that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to send and receive message only one time? Then you can use Unsubscribe method after you receive the message. For example, you can do like this:

```
 MessagingCenter.Subscribe<MyPage, string>(this, "Invoke", async (sender, 
   arg) =>
{
await Process(arg); 
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<MyPage>(this,"Invoke");
});
```

**Updated**:

On `DetailPage`,  you can call `MessagingCenter.Subscribe` in method `OnAppearing()` and call `MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe` in method `OnDisappearing` , just as follows:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
       MessagingCenter.Subscribe<ListPage, string>(this, "Invoke", async (sender, arg) =>
        {
            Debug.Write("123456---->  get one msg");
            DisplayAlert("Alert", "We have received a message.", "OK");
        });
    }

    protected async override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        base.OnDisappearing();
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<ListPage,string>(this, "Invoke");
    }
}
```

On `ListPage`

```
async void OnTap (object sender, EventArgs e)  
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage());
        try
        {

            MessagingCenter.Send(this, "Invoke", "Invokedtrue");

            Debug.Write("123456---->  send one msg");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.Write(ex);
        }

    }
```

Note: when you enter into `ListPage`, you can try the following code:

```
  MainPage = new  NavigationPage( new ListPage());
```

The effect  in IOS is : 
[image]

The link of full demo is [here](https://github.com/jessiezh0320/MesseageCenterApp), you can check it.

Comment: I have try with this but when user click on second time than also not getting subscribe in my page. Can you please give other best solution?

Comment: @DeepSoni Do you  want to get the message again after that ? The mechanism of  MessagingCenter is to send once and receive once， unless you unsubscribe it. Could you please share more code snippet about MessagingCenter in your app?

Comment: I add my code in a question can you please look into that and suggest me what should I have to  change?

Comment: @DeepSoni  I have updated the answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for response. I have try with your code and works fine on `android` but when I move platform to `iOS` than it doesn't work for me.
Can you please check and share possible way that work good on both platform.

Comment: @DeepSoni  The MessagingCenter is fine. What we need to pay attention to is the push and pop styles of the page. I have updated the answer , you can check it.

Comment: Thanks for response. Let I try with your updated code in both platform.

Comment: I have tried what you have mentioned still the subscribe get called twice.